# Find value on unordered_map

Tags: c++, unordered-map

So in the beginning  i had an unordered_map with an int as the key and string as the value initialized with 256 ASCII characters but later i found myself in the need to search for a string in the dictionnary but i couldnt use map::find since my key is an int . 
So here is my question how can i search for a specific value in an unordered map? or how should i modify this method to initialize all ASCII characters in a unordered_map where the key is a string and i could use map::find?

```
void InitDico (unordered_map<int,string>& Dico){
   Dico.clear();
   for (int i = 0; i < 256; ++i)
   {
       Dico[i] = (char)i;
   }}
```

What i tried :

```
void InitDico (unordered_map<string,int>& Dico){
   Dico.clear();
   for (int i = 0; i < 256; ++i)
   {
       Dico.insert({(char)i , i});  
   }}
```

Comment: Are you saying that the map always has 256 elements, mapping ASCII character codes to the characters themselves? If so, you don't need the map at all.

Comment: new strings will be added to the map i'm trying to code an LZW data compressor using this algorithm https://www2.cs.duke.edu/csed/curious/compression/lzw.html so i need to initialize the dictionary with all ASCII characters before adding anything to it .

Comment: `char` is not a `std::string`. Use `Dico.insert({std::to_string(i) , i});`

Comment: @super I will try that asap ty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So tanks to super i did it , i've done a really dumb mistake....  so here is the code :

```
void InitDico2(unordered_map<string,int>& Dico) {
Dico.clear();
string s ="";
char c;
for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
{
    c = (char)i;
    s += c;
    Dico[s] = i;
    s.clear();

}}
```

Answer (score 1):

`std::string` has a constructor that takes a count and a `char`, and constructs a string of count repetitions of that `char`.

[It is implementation-defined whether a `char` object can hold negative values.](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.fundamental#1)

```
void InitDico2(std::unordered_map<std::string,int>& Dico) {
    Dico.clear();
    for (unsigned char c = 0; c < 256; c++)
    {
        Dico[{1, c}] = c;
    }    
}
```